# Stop an unknown function from running after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a function `someFunction()` that i don't any control of what inside of it.
I wish to run this function for no more than 5 seconds.

I've tried using a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` like this:

```
try {
   const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      throw new Error("Time over");
   }, 5000);

   someFunction();
   clearTimeout(timeoutId);
} catch (e) {
   ...
}
```

The problem in this is that if there is an infinite loop in `someFunction()` then the timeout will never get called.

what's the simplest way to solve this? I thought about using a worker thread but passing arguments to another thread is problematic in my case.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: JavaScript does not support multi-threading, so this is difficult to achieve. As its a single thread, if the function is stuck in a loop, you will not get past it. If the timeout stops the function for a few seconds, it stops the thread.

What you may need to do is have a look at asynchronous functions. I don't know if it would be possible to do what you want, but perhaps sticking a timeout function in an asynchronous function will allow you to achieve what you are setting out todo. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299246/12227695

Comment: A `setTimeout` callback requires at least one event loop cycle in order to be called. If your function executes code for more than 5 seconds, then it will prevent the event loop to continue for that duration (see “blocking”). You’ll have to use worker threads. You can also try doing the work in batches, if possible, use some kind of non-blocking code (e.g. another `setTimeout`) to continue with the next batch, then resolve a Promise with the result.

Comment: Would probably be most helpful to describe your real problem, rather than ask how to achieve your desired solution

Comment: To elaborate on my above comment, without knowing anything else about the problem you're having, my immediate guess is you probably want to use a queue/worker system

Comment: @Adam you are absolutely right. The problem I'm facing is that i'm trying to run a code i receive as a string. i create this `someFunction` using `const someFunction = new Function(externalCode)`. I want to pass this unknown function arguments that use my current context (This is why I wanted to avoid using another thread).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what's the simplest way to solve this?

You can't, within the same execution environment. If you don't control what's inside the function, there's no way for you to stop it from your code. Once you've made the call to `someFunction`, your code doesn't get control back until that function has run to completion.¹ If it loops infinitely, it loops infinitely.

You *could* spawn a [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) that runs the function in a separate environment, which you can then terminate ([1](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#workerterminate), [2](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal)) after a period of time. But within your main environment, you can't do it.

---

¹ Note that in the case of an `async` function, "run(s) to completion" means "reaches the point where it returns its promise" (the first `await`, `return` [implicit or explicit], or uncaught error). So in theory if you had an `async` function that started something then didn't go into the finite loop until after the first `await` (say), your code would get an opportunity to run, but if you have no control over the function's code there's nothing you can do from keeping it from continuing again (other than run an infinite loop of your own, which of course you wouldn't want to do).